# Not sure which of two questions to link as duplicate, if any (re: 'goto' in Java)

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

There are two highly similar, arguably identical questions:

- [goto keyword in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334376/goto-keyword-in-java) (26 August 2009, +8, 11 answers, 9k views)
- [Is there a goto statement in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java) (30 March 2010, +84, 17 answers, 124k views)

In my opinion either they should be merged or one marked as a duplicate of the other. I am inclined to mark the earlier as a duplicate of the later one, simply based on votes, popularity, and answer quality. The top answers on the earlier one are also good, though, even though they are redundant with some of the answers on the later one.

What, if anything, should be done here? Should they be merged? Just mark earlier as a duplicate and forget about it? Nothing?

Comment: It's the same question (with an insignificant amount of re-phrasing), so an excellent merge-candidate.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm not actually sure what proper etiquette for requesting a merge is. Should I just raise a flag on one of them with a comment like "request merge with <link to second>, see discussion on meta at <link to this meta question>"?

Comment: safest way would be to spell flag message about like this: `please take a look, merge of this question with a similar one is being discussed at meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275516/not-sure-which-of-two-questions-to-link-as-duplicate-if-any-re-goto-in-java`